# Read out loud feature on acroread

Tags: adobe, adobe-reader

I just installed adobe reader 9(acroread ) package from the ubuntu software center. I am trying to activate the read out loud feature but it doesn't seem to work. 
I have tried fixes mentioned everywhere:
I installed libgnome-speech7 package and ran:

```
sudo /var/lib/dpkg/info/acroread.postinst configure
```

The output of this command turns out to be:

```
No LSB modules are available.
```

Does anyone know how to get read out loud work? 
Also, I am not able to get the adobe reader browser plugin to work. I installed the  ia32-libs package since I am on a 64-bit system. 
But, no dice. The browser plugin is also not working.
Could anybody please help me out here?

Comment: I can't even find a way to open documents from the UI with it as I'm having the same problem.  It doesn't show up in the list of available applications.

Answer (score 0):

Install lsb:

```
sudo apt-get install lsb-core
```